# match array of value with another object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to this, I've a array of object like below,

```
arr1 = {
    "ID": "sss",
    "Name": "Ven"
    "Main": [
        {"ID": "asds-vg45"},
        {"ID": "rrra-2e82"}
    ]
}
```

and another object of values like below,

```
obj1 = {
    "AID": "ssasas222",
    "Main": {
    "asds-vg45" : {
        "NAME" : "Item1",
        "STML" : {
            "MIKE" : {
                "bearer" : {
                    "token" : "ya29.Gl0kBoYJD"
                },
                "STA" : true
            }
        },
        "STATUS" : true
    },
    "rrra-2e82" : {
        "NAME" : "Item2",
        "STML" : {
            "MIKE" : {
                "bearer" : {
                    "token" : "yas9.Gl0kBoYJD"
                },
                "STA" : true
            }
        },
        "STATUS" : true
    },
    "t655e-2e82" : {
        "NAME" : "Item2",
        "STML" : {
            "MIKE" : {
                "bearer" : {
                    "token" : "yas9.Gl0kBoYJD"
                },
                "STA" : true
            }
        },
        "STATUS" : true
    }
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to get it a new object which includes all the values matching in obj1 of "Main" object with "arr1" and also the the "ID" in "obj1", the matching ID here are the one's in "Main" array which is common in both, the output that I'm trying to get is something like below,

```
main_obj = {
    "ID": "sss",
    "Name": "Ven",
    "AID": "ssasas222"
    "Main": {
        "asds-vg45" : {
            "NAME" : "Item1",
            "STML" : {
                "MIKE" : {
                    "bearer" : {
                        "token" : "ya29.Gl0kBoYJD"
                    },
                    "STA" : true
                }
            },
            "STATUS" : true
        },
        "rrra-2e82" : {
            "NAME" : "Item2",
            "STML" : {
                "MIKE" : {
                    "bearer" : {
                        "token" : "yas9.Gl0kBoYJD"
                    },
                    "STA" : true
                }
            },
            "STATUS" : true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. It will be easier for us to help you that way.

Comment: btw, your *arrays* are objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the keys and the object of the given data for a new object.

```js
var data = { AID: "ssasas222", Main: { "asds-vg45": { NAME: "Item1", STML: { MIKE: { bearer: { token: "ya29.Gl0kBoYJD" }, STA: true } }, STATUS: true }, "rrra-2e82": { NAME: "Item2", STML: { MIKE: { bearer: { token: "yas9.Gl0kBoYJD" }, STA: true } }, STATUS: true }, "t655e-2e82": { NAME: "Item2", STML: { MIKE: { bearer: { token: "yas9.Gl0kBoYJD" }, STA: true } }, STATUS: true } } },
    filter = { ID: "sss", Name: "Ven", Main: [{ ID: "asds-vg45" }, { ID: "rrra-2e82" }] },
    result = Object.assign(
        {},
        data,
        { Main: Object.assign(...filter.Main.map(({ ID }) => ({ [ID]: data.Main[ID] }))) }
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with `reduce`:

```
const matches = arr1.Main
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (obj1.Main[cur.ID]) {
      acc[cur.ID]: obj1.Main[cur.ID]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

const mainObj = {
  ID: arr1.ID,
  Name: arr1.Name,
  AID: obj1.AID,
  Main: matches
}
```

You just loop over the array of IDs and build up a new object, `acc`, with the keys that match.